# pandas - lambda function on dataframe - Am I using it incorrectly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i'm attempting to apply a calculation to my dataframe row by row

below is my code, but it's taking hours to run and sometimes never finishing, what am I doing wrong here?

The code is supposed to run the FindLL function on each row of the database..

```
postcode_geo = []

with open (r'Desktop\Python Projects\Work - Transport Movement\open_postcode_geo.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        postcode_geo.append(row)

#function to find lat,lon of given postcode
postcode_geo_postcodes = [x[0] for x in postcode_geo]

def FindLL(postcode):
    if postcode in postcode_geo_postcodes:
        for x in range(0,len(postcode_geo)):
            if postcode == postcode_geo[x][0]:
                latitude = postcode_geo[x][7]
                longitude = postcode_geo[x][8]
                return f'{longitude},{latitude}'  
    else:
        return "Postcode can't find longitude/latitude, please check format"

df = pd.read_excel(r'Desktop\Python Projects\Work - Transport Movement\Transport Movement P10\TransportMovementP10.xlsx')

df[f'Start Postcode LL'] = df.apply(lambda row: FindLL(row['ESP_START_LOCATION_POSTCODE']), axis = 1)
df[f'End Postcode LL'] = df.apply(lambda row: FindLL(row['ESP_END_LOCATION_POSTCODE']), axis = 1)

print(df)
```

So the dataframe is roughly 68,000 rows of data and around 22 columns, but i'm only using 2 of those columns

The postcode geo file is around 1.2million rows

Comment: Could you share a sample of the datasets you are using?

Comment: It's 68,000 rows and 22 columns and the csv postcode geo file is around 1.2 million rows.

Comment: The problem in your code is basically that you are using for loops and lambdas functions in datasets with 1 million rows. You should always try to use vectorization.  If you share with us a couple of rows of the datasets you are using we could come up with a more efficient solution.